# Bootstrap 4 navbar prevent button wrapping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I want the search bar to shrink on mobile view and everything to stay inline. Currently the button wraps around underneath the search bar.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/endaM/koe6mzf6/6/)

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.navbar-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
 <div class="container navbar-container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
   <img src="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
 </a>
 <form class="form-inline ">
   <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Search">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" type="submit">Go</button>
  </form>
 </div>

</nav>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to make the form `display:flex`..

```
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
 <div class="container navbar-container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
   <img src="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
 </a>
 <form class="form-inline d-flex">
   <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Search">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" type="submit">Go</button>
  </form>
 </div>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gdjwdjmq/

---

Also, it would be best to use the stable release of **Bootstrap 4.0.0** 
It's flexbox by default and you won't need the extra CSS...

https://www.codeply.com/go/BB1lcTDE71